# Graphics glitches on ubuntu 20.04 LTS Xorg - AMD Ryzen 5 3500U / Radeon Vega 8

Tags: 20.04, xorg, amd-ryzen, amdgpu-pro

I installed ubuntu 20.04 on a laptop with an AMD Ryzen 5 3500U and a integrated graphic card Radeon Vega 8 also i installed the amdgpu PRO drivers without any problem. when i initialize ubuntu with Xorg server appears a very serous graphics glitches, especially when i open any application :[image: terminal bugged]

More information about my system here:

kernel version:

```
5.8.0-43-generic
```

inxi -Gx:

```
Graphics:  Device-1: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Picasso vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: amdgpu v: kernel bus ID: 03:00.0 
       Display: wayland server: X.Org 1.20.9 driver: amdgpu resolution: 1366x768~60Hz 
       OpenGL: renderer: AMD Radeon Graphics v: 4.6.14756 Core Profile Context direct render: Yes
```

Xorg logs:

```
[   187.101] (--) Log file renamed from "/home/juan/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.pid-1716.log" to "/home/juan/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log"
[   187.102] 
X.Org X Server 1.20.9
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[   187.102] Build Operating System: Linux 4.15.0-130-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
[   187.102] Current Operating System: Linux juan-HP-245-G7-Notebook-PC 5.8.0-43-generic #49~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 5 09:57:56 UTC 2021 x86_64
[   187.102] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.8.0-43-generic root=UUID=0c283602-f714-4870-800e-87cc33d69e01 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
[   187.102] Build Date: 17 January 2021  09:13:31AM
[   187.102] xorg-server 2:1.20.9-2ubuntu1.2~20.04.1 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
[   187.102] Current version of pixman: 0.38.4
[   187.102]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[   187.102] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[   187.102] (==) Log file: "/home/juan/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log", Time: Wed Mar  3 13:28:45 2021
[   187.196] (==) Using config directory: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[   187.196] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[   187.893] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[   187.894] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[   187.894] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[   187.894] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[   187.963] (==) No device specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using the first device section listed.
[   187.963] (**) |   |-->Device "AMD"
[   187.963] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[   187.963] (==) Automatically adding devices
[   187.963] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[   187.963] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[   187.963] (==) Automatically binding GPU devices
[   187.963] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[   187.963] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[   187.963]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   187.963] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[   187.963]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   187.963] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[   187.963]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   187.963] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[   187.963]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   187.963] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[   187.963]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   187.963] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    built-ins
[   187.963] (**) ModulePath set to "/opt/amdgpu-pro/lib/xorg/modules,/opt/amdgpu/lib/xorg/modules,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[   187.963] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[   187.963] (II) Loader magic: 0x5581966b7020
[   187.963] (II) Module ABI versions:
[   187.963]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[   187.963]    X.Org Video Driver: 24.1
[   187.963]    X.Org XInput driver : 24.1
[   187.963]    X.Org Server Extension : 10.0
[   187.964] (++) using VT number 2

[   187.968] (II) systemd-logind: took control of session /org/freedesktop/login1/session/_32
[   187.969] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[   187.972] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/dri/card0 226:0 fd 12 paused 0
[   187.976] (--) PCI:*(3@0:0:0) 1002:15d8:103c:85b1 rev 194, Mem @ 0xe0000000/268435456, 0xf0000000/2097152, 0xfcc00000/524288, I/O @ 0x0000d000/256
[   188.090] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[   188.376] (II) Loading /opt/amdgpu-pro/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[   188.563] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   188.563]    compiled for 1.20.1, module version = 1.0.0
[   188.563]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 10.0
[   188.564] (II) LoadModule: "amdgpu"
[   188.588] (II) Loading /opt/amdgpu/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/amdgpu_drv.so
[   188.796] (II) Module amdgpu: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   188.796]    compiled for 1.20.8, module version = 19.1.0
[   188.796]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   188.796]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.1
[   188.796] (II) AMDGPU: Driver for AMD Radeon:
    All GPUs supported by the amdgpu kernel driver
[   188.799] (WW) VGA arbiter: cannot open kernel arbiter, no multi-card support
[   188.799] (II) AMDGPU(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
    "Default Screen Section" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
[   188.799] (==) AMDGPU(0): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
[   188.799] (II) AMDGPU(0): Pixel depth = 24 bits stored in 4 bytes (32 bpp pixmaps)
[   188.799] (==) AMDGPU(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[   188.799] (**) AMDGPU(0): Option "TearFree" "true"
[   188.799] (==) AMDGPU(0): RGB weight 888
[   188.799] (II) AMDGPU(0): Using 8 bits per RGB (8 bit DAC)
[   188.799] (--) AMDGPU(0): Chipset: "Unknown AMD Radeon GPU" (ChipID = 0x15d8)
[   188.799] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[   188.799] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[   188.850] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[   188.891] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   188.891]    compiled for 1.20.9, module version = 1.0.0
[   188.891]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[   188.891] (II) Loading sub module "dri2"
[   188.891] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
[   188.891] (II) Module "dri2" already built-in
[   188.908] (II) Loading sub module "glamoregl"
[   188.908] (II) LoadModule: "glamoregl"
[   188.908] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libglamoregl.so
[   188.947] (II) Module glamoregl: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   188.947]    compiled for 1.20.9, module version = 1.0.1
[   188.947]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[   189.369] (II) AMDGPU(0): glamor X acceleration enabled on AMD Radeon Graphics
[   189.369] (II) AMDGPU(0): glamor detected, initialising EGL layer.
[   189.369] (**) AMDGPU(0): TearFree property default: on
[   189.369] (==) AMDGPU(0): VariableRefresh: disabled
[   189.369] (II) AMDGPU(0): KMS Pageflipping: enabled
[   189.369] (II) AMDGPU(0): Output eDP has no monitor section
[   189.369] (II) AMDGPU(0): Output HDMI-A-0 has no monitor section
[   189.369] (II) AMDGPU(0): Output DisplayPort-0 has no monitor section
[   189.378] (II) AMDGPU(0): EDID for output eDP
[   189.378] (II) AMDGPU(0): Manufacturer: CMN  Model: 14c3  Serial#: 0
[   189.378] (II) AMDGPU(0): Year: 2016  Week: 19
[   189.378] (II) AMDGPU(0): EDID Version: 1.4
[   189.378] (II) AMDGPU(0): Digital Display Input
[   189.378] (II) AMDGPU(0): 6 bits per channel
[   189.378] (II) AMDGPU(0): Digital interface is DisplayPort
[   189.378] (II) AMDGPU(0): Max Image Size [cm]: horiz.: 31  vert.: 17
[   189.378] (II) AMDGPU(0): Gamma: 2.20
[   189.378] (II) AMDGPU(0): No DPMS capabilities specified
[   189.378] (II) AMDGPU(0): Supported color encodings: RGB 4:4:4 
[   189.378] (II) AMDGPU(0): First detailed timing is preferred mode
[   189.378] (II) AMDGPU(0): Preferred mode is native pixel format and refresh rate
[   189.379] (II) AMDGPU(0): redX: 0.575 redY: 0.335   greenX: 0.327 greenY: 0.580
[   189.379] (II) AMDGPU(0): blueX: 0.157 blueY: 0.137   whiteX: 0.313 whiteY: 0.329
[   189.379] (II) AMDGPU(0): Manufacturer's mask: 0
[   189.379] (II) AMDGPU(0): Supported detailed timing:
[   189.379] (II) AMDGPU(0): clock: 76.4 MHz   Image Size:  309 x 173 mm
[   189.379] (II) AMDGPU(0): h_active: 1366  h_sync: 1434  h_sync_end 1479 h_blank_end 1592 h_border: 0
[   189.379] (II) AMDGPU(0): v_active: 768  v_sync: 772  v_sync_end 779 v_blanking: 800 v_border: 0
[   189.379] (II) AMDGPU(0): Supported detailed timing:
[   189.379] (II) AMDGPU(0): clock: 51.0 MHz   Image Size:  309 x 173 mm
[   189.379] (II) AMDGPU(0): h_active: 1366  h_sync: 1434  h_sync_end 1479 h_blank_end 1592 h_border: 0
[   189.379] (II) AMDGPU(0): v_active: 768  v_sync: 772  v_sync_end 779 v_blanking: 800 v_border: 0
[   189.379] (II) AMDGPU(0): Unknown vendor-specific block 2
[   189.379] (II) AMDGPU(0): EDID (in hex):
[   189.379] (II) AMDGPU(0):    00ffffffffffff000daec31400000000
[   189.379] (II) AMDGPU(0):    131a0104951f1178027e459355539428
[   189.379] (II) AMDGPU(0):    23505400000001010101010101010101
[   189.379] (II) AMDGPU(0):    010101010101da1d56e250002030442d
[   189.379] (II) AMDGPU(0):    470035ad1000001ae71356e250002030
[   189.379] (II) AMDGPU(0):    442d470035ad1000001a000000000000
[   189.379] (II) AMDGPU(0):    00000000000000000000000000000002
[   189.379] (II) AMDGPU(0):    000c44ff0b3c6e0f0f1b6e000000009c
[   189.379] (II) AMDGPU(0): Printing probed modes for output eDP
[   189.379] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1366x768"x60.0   76.42  1366 1434 1479 1592  768 772 779 800 +hsync -vsync (48.0 kHz eP)
[   189.379] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1366x768"x40.0   50.95  1366 1434 1479 1592  768 772 779 800 +hsync -vsync (32.0 kHz e)
[   189.379] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1280x720"x60.0   76.42  1280 1434 1479 1592  720 772 779 800 +hsync -vsync (48.0 kHz e)
[   189.379] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1024x768"x60.0   76.42  1024 1434 1479 1592  768 772 779 800 +hsync -vsync (48.0 kHz e)
[   189.379] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "800x600"x60.0   76.42  800 1434 1479 1592  600 772 779 800 +hsync -vsync (48.0 kHz e)
[   189.379] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "640x480"x60.0   76.42  640 1434 1479 1592  480 772 779 800 +hsync -vsync (48.0 kHz e)
[   189.379] (II) AMDGPU(0): EDID for output HDMI-A-0
[   189.379] (II) AMDGPU(0): EDID for output DisplayPort-0
[   189.379] (II) AMDGPU(0): Output eDP connected
[   189.379] (II) AMDGPU(0): Output HDMI-A-0 disconnected
[   189.379] (II) AMDGPU(0): Output DisplayPort-0 disconnected
[   189.379] (II) AMDGPU(0): Using exact sizes for initial modes
[   189.379] (II) AMDGPU(0): Output eDP using initial mode 1366x768 +0+0
[   189.379] (II) AMDGPU(0): mem size init: gart size :bf6cc000 vram size: s:7e3b6000 visible:5eac8800
[   189.379] (II) AMDGPU(0): Video RAM: 2068184 kByte
[   189.379] (==) AMDGPU(0): DPI set to (96, 96)
[   189.379] (==) AMDGPU(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[   189.379] (II) Loading sub module "ramdac"
[   189.379] (II) LoadModule: "ramdac"
[   189.379] (II) Module "ramdac" already built-in
[   189.403] (II) AMDGPU(0): [DRI2] Setup complete
[   189.403] (II) AMDGPU(0): [DRI2]   DRI driver: radeonsi
[   189.403] (II) AMDGPU(0): [DRI2]   VDPAU driver: radeonsi
[   189.403] (II) AMDGPU(0): Front buffer pitch: 5632 bytes
[   189.411] (II) AMDGPU(0): SYNC extension fences enabled
[   189.423] (II) AMDGPU(0): Present extension enabled
[   189.423] (==) AMDGPU(0): DRI3 enabled
[   189.423] (==) AMDGPU(0): Backing store enabled
[   189.423] (II) AMDGPU(0): Direct rendering enabled
[   189.436] (II) AMDGPU(0): Use GLAMOR acceleration.
[   189.436] (II) AMDGPU(0): Acceleration enabled
[   189.436] (==) AMDGPU(0): DPMS enabled
[   189.436] (==) AMDGPU(0): Silken mouse enabled
[   189.436] (II) AMDGPU(0): Set up textured video (glamor)
[   189.445] (II) Initializing extension Generic Event Extension
[   189.445] (II) Initializing extension SHAPE
[   189.445] (II) Initializing extension MIT-SHM
[   189.445] (II) Initializing extension XInputExtension
[   189.446] (II) Initializing extension XTEST
[   189.446] (II) Initializing extension BIG-REQUESTS
[   189.446] (II) Initializing extension SYNC
[   189.446] (II) Initializing extension XKEYBOARD
[   189.446] (II) Initializing extension XC-MISC
[   189.447] (II) Initializing extension SECURITY
[   189.447] (II) Initializing extension XFIXES
[   189.447] (II) Initializing extension RENDER
[   189.447] (II) Initializing extension RANDR
[   189.447] (II) Initializing extension COMPOSITE
[   189.447] (II) Initializing extension DAMAGE
[   189.447] (II) Initializing extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
[   189.448] (II) Initializing extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
[   189.448] (II) Initializing extension RECORD
[   189.448] (II) Initializing extension DPMS
[   189.448] (II) Initializing extension Present
[   189.448] (II) Initializing extension DRI3
[   189.448] (II) Initializing extension X-Resource
[   189.448] (II) Initializing extension XVideo
[   189.448] (II) Initializing extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
[   189.448] (II) Initializing extension SELinux
[   189.448] (II) SELinux: Disabled on system
[   189.448] (II) Initializing extension GLX
[   189.459] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer
[   189.459] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_ARB_create_context
[   189.459] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_ARB_create_context_profile
[   189.459] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile
[   189.459] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_INTEL_swap_event
[   189.459] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_SGI_swap_control and GLX_MESA_swap_control
[   189.459] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB
[   189.459] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float
[   189.459] (II) AIGLX: GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap backed by buffer objects
[   189.460] (II) AIGLX: Loaded and initialized radeonsi
[   189.460] (II) GLX: Initialized DRI2 GL provider for screen 0
[   189.460] (II) Initializing extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
[   189.460] (II) Initializing extension XFree86-DGA
[   189.460] (II) Initializing extension XFree86-DRI
[   189.460] (II) Initializing extension DRI2
[   189.463] (II) AMDGPU(0): Setting screen physical size to 361 x 203
[   189.517] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event2)
[   189.517] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[   189.517] (II) LoadModule: "libinput"
[   189.517] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/libinput_drv.so
[   189.551] (II) Module libinput: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   189.551]    compiled for 1.20.4, module version = 0.29.0
[   189.551]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[   189.551]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 24.1
[   189.551] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Power Button'
[   189.552] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event2 13:66 fd 25 paused 0
[   189.552] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[   189.552] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event2"
[   189.553] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[   189.556] (II) event2  - Power Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[   189.556] (II) event2  - Power Button: device is a keyboard
[   189.556] (II) event2  - Power Button: device removed
[   189.556] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input2/event2"
[   189.556] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 6)
[   189.556] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[   189.556] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "es"
[   189.579] (II) event2  - Power Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[   189.579] (II) event2  - Power Button: device is a keyboard
[   189.580] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Video Bus (/dev/input/event4)
[   189.580] (**) Video Bus: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[   189.580] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Video Bus'
[   189.581] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event4 13:68 fd 28 paused 0
[   189.581] (**) Video Bus: always reports core events
[   189.581] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event4"
[   189.581] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[   189.582] (II) event4  - Video Bus: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[   189.582] (II) event4  - Video Bus: device is a keyboard
[   189.582] (II) event4  - Video Bus: device removed
[   189.582] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:04/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input5/event4"
[   189.582] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Video Bus" (type: KEYBOARD, id 7)
[   189.582] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[   189.583] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "es"
[   189.584] (II) event4  - Video Bus: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[   189.584] (II) event4  - Video Bus: device is a keyboard
[   189.584] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event0)
[   189.584] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[   189.584] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Power Button'
[   189.585] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event0 13:64 fd 29 paused 0
[   189.585] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[   189.585] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event0"
[   189.585] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[   189.586] (II) event0  - Power Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[   189.586] (II) event0  - Power Button: device is a keyboard
[   189.586] (II) event0  - Power Button: device removed
[   189.586] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input0/event0"
[   189.586] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 8)
[   189.586] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[   189.586] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "es"
[   189.587] (II) event0  - Power Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[   189.587] (II) event0  - Power Button: device is a keyboard
[   189.588] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Lid Switch (/dev/input/event1)
[   189.588] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   189.588] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   189.588] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HD-Audio Generic HDMI/DP,pcm=3 (/dev/input/event9)
[   189.588] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   189.588] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   189.589] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HP TrueVision HD Camera: HP Tru (/dev/input/event8)
[   189.589] (**) HP TrueVision HD Camera: HP Tru: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[   189.589] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'HP TrueVision HD Camera: HP Tru'
[   189.591] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event8 13:72 fd 30 paused 0
[   189.591] (**) HP TrueVision HD Camera: HP Tru: always reports core events
[   189.591] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event8"
[   189.591] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[   189.593] (II) event8  - HP TrueVision HD Camera: HP Tru: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[   189.593] (II) event8  - HP TrueVision HD Camera: HP Tru: device is a keyboard
[   189.594] (II) event8  - HP TrueVision HD Camera: HP Tru: device removed
[   189.594] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:03:00.3/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0/input/input9/event8"
[   189.594] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "HP TrueVision HD Camera: HP Tru" (type: KEYBOARD, id 9)
[   189.594] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[   189.594] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "es"
[   189.596] (II) event8  - HP TrueVision HD Camera: HP Tru: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[   189.596] (II) event8  - HP TrueVision HD Camera: HP Tru: device is a keyboard
[   189.597] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HD-Audio Generic Mic (/dev/input/event10)
[   189.597] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   189.597] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   189.597] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HD-Audio Generic Headphone (/dev/input/event11)
[   189.597] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   189.597] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   189.598] (II) config/udev: Adding input device AT Translated Set 2 keyboard (/dev/input/event3)
[   189.598] (**) AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[   189.598] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'AT Translated Set 2 keyboard'
[   189.599] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event3 13:67 fd 31 paused 0
[   189.599] (**) AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: always reports core events
[   189.599] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event3"
[   189.599] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[   189.600] (II) event3  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[   189.601] (II) event3  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: device is a keyboard
[   189.601] (II) event3  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: device removed
[   189.601] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input3/event3"
[   189.601] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "AT Translated Set 2 keyboard" (type: KEYBOARD, id 10)
[   189.601] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[   189.601] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "es"
[   189.603] (II) event3  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[   189.603] (II) event3  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: device is a keyboard
[   189.604] (II) config/udev: Adding input device ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad (/dev/input/event5)
[   189.604] (**) ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: Applying InputClass "libinput touchpad catchall"
[   189.604] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad'
[   189.604] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event5 13:69 fd 32 paused 0
[   189.604] (**) ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: always reports core events
[   189.604] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event5"
[   189.604] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[   189.605] (II) event5  - ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: is tagged by udev as: Touchpad
[   189.605] (II) event5  - ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: device is a touchpad
[   189.606] (II) event5  - ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: device removed
[   189.606] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input6/event5"
[   189.606] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad" (type: TOUCHPAD, id 11)
[   189.606] (**) Option "AccelerationScheme" "none"
[   189.606] (**) ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: (accel) selected scheme none/0
[   189.606] (**) ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[   189.606] (**) ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[   189.607] (II) event5  - ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: is tagged by udev as: Touchpad
[   189.607] (II) event5  - ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: device is a touchpad
[   189.607] (II) config/udev: Adding input device ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad (/dev/input/mouse0)
[   189.607] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   189.607] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   189.609] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HP Wireless hotkeys (/dev/input/event6)
[   189.609] (**) HP Wireless hotkeys: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[   189.609] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'HP Wireless hotkeys'
[   189.609] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event6 13:70 fd 33 paused 0
[   189.609] (**) HP Wireless hotkeys: always reports core events
[   189.609] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event6"
[   189.609] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[   189.610] (II) event6  - HP Wireless hotkeys: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[   189.610] (II) event6  - HP Wireless hotkeys: device is a keyboard
[   189.610] (II) event6  - HP Wireless hotkeys: device removed
[   189.610] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/virtual/input/input7/event6"
[   189.610] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "HP Wireless hotkeys" (type: KEYBOARD, id 12)
[   189.610] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[   189.610] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "es"
[   189.611] (II) event6  - HP Wireless hotkeys: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[   189.611] (II) event6  - HP Wireless hotkeys: device is a keyboard
[   189.611] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HP WMI hotkeys (/dev/input/event7)
[   189.611] (**) HP WMI hotkeys: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[   189.611] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'HP WMI hotkeys'
[   189.612] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event7 13:71 fd 34 paused 0
[   189.612] (**) HP WMI hotkeys: always reports core events
[   189.612] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event7"
[   189.612] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[   189.612] (II) event7  - HP WMI hotkeys: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard Switch
[   189.612] (II) event7  - HP WMI hotkeys: device is a keyboard
[   189.612] (II) event7  - HP WMI hotkeys: device is a switch device
[   189.612] (II) event7  - HP WMI hotkeys: device removed
[   189.612] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/virtual/input/input8/event7"
[   189.612] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "HP WMI hotkeys" (type: KEYBOARD, id 13)
[   189.612] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[   189.612] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "es"
[   189.613] (II) event7  - HP WMI hotkeys: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard Switch
[   189.613] (II) event7  - HP WMI hotkeys: device is a keyboard
[   189.613] (II) event7  - HP WMI hotkeys: device is a switch device
[   198.285] (II) AMDGPU(0): EDID vendor "CMN", prod id 5315
[   198.285] (II) AMDGPU(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[   198.285] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1366x768"x0.0   76.42  1366 1434 1479 1592  768 772 779 800 +hsync -vsync (48.0 kHz eP)
[   198.285] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1366x768"x0.0   50.95  1366 1434 1479 1592  768 772 779 800 +hsync -vsync (32.0 kHz e)
[   612.670] (**) Option "fd" "25"
[   612.670] (II) event2  - Power Button: device removed
[   612.670] (**) Option "fd" "28"
[   612.670] (II) event4  - Video Bus: device removed
[   612.670] (**) Option "fd" "29"
[   612.670] (II) event0  - Power Button: device removed
[   612.670] (**) Option "fd" "30"
[   612.670] (II) event8  - HP TrueVision HD Camera: HP Tru: device removed
[   612.670] (**) Option "fd" "31"
[   612.670] (II) event3  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: device removed
[   612.670] (**) Option "fd" "32"
[   612.670] (II) event5  - ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: device removed
[   612.670] (**) Option "fd" "33"
[   612.670] (II) event6  - HP Wireless hotkeys: device removed
[   612.670] (**) Option "fd" "34"
[   612.670] (II) event7  - HP WMI hotkeys: device removed
[   612.671] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[   612.672] (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:71
[   612.780] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[   612.901] (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:70
[   612.954] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[   612.954] (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:69
[   613.003] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[   613.003] (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:67
[   613.026] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[   613.026] (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:72
[   613.066] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[   613.066] (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:64
[   613.086] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[   613.086] (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:68
[   613.127] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[   613.127] (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:66
[   613.153] (WW) xf86CloseConsole: KDSETMODE failed: Input/output error
[   613.153] (WW) xf86CloseConsole: VT_GETMODE failed: Input/output error
[   613.153] (WW) xf86CloseConsole: VT_ACTIVATE failed: Input/output error
[   613.197] (II) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.
```

xorg.conf:

```
Section "Device"
        Identifier "AMD"
        Driver  "amdgpu"
        Option "TearFree" "true"
EndSection
```